# CakePHP Many To Many With Conditions

Tags: cakephp, orm, many-to-many, cakephp-2.0

I'm newbie on CakePHP, and now I'm stuck on many to many situation

ok, i have 3 Table :

1. questions
   with fields (id, question)
2. question_product
   with fields (id, question_id, product_id, question_number, is_enabled)
3. products
   with fields (id, name, code, is_enabled)

so when i want to select questions with specific field, i don't know how to fix it
for now, my code is like this :

Question.php (Model)

```
class Question extends AppModel {

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
        'Product' => array (
            'joinTable' => 'question_product',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'product_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'order' => 'question_number',
            'fields' => array (
                'QuestionProduct.question_number',
                'Product.id',
                'Product.name'
            ),
            'conditions' => array (
                'QuestionProduct.is_enabled' => 1,
            )
        )
    );
}
```

QuestionsController.php (Controller)

```
public function loadQuestions($productId) {
    $this->view = 'load_questions';
    $questions = $this->Question->find('all', array (
        'fields' => array (
            'Question.id',
            'Question.question',
            'Question.is_optional',
            'Question.reason_optional',
            'Question.text_size'
        ),
        'conditions' => array (
            'QuestionProduct.product_id' => $productId
        )
    ));
    $this->set($questions);
}
```

method loadQuestions have one parameter to select with specified product

if i using sql query, it will be like this

select all from Question with condition Product.product_id=4, sorted by QuestionProduct.question_number ascending

```
select questions.*
from questions
join question_product on questions.id=question_product.question_id
join products on products.id=question_product.product_id
where products.id=4
order by question_product.question_number;
```

any answer will be appreciated :)

Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify what the problem is and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jeremyharris thanks for reply.. i already added sql query, may u have a clue for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Any time you use a many-many (HABTM) relation with any other field that requires conditions, it is no longer many-many as far as Cake is concerned. You want the [HasManyThrough relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation, use two `belongsTO` relation from **question_product** to **questions** and another time from **question_product** to **products**.

> **question_product belognsTo questions**
>
> **question_product belongsTo products**

**NOTE:you should change the table name from question_product to question_products as cakePHP convention**

in your model QuestionProduct model :

```
<?php

// declares a package for a class
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class QuestionProduct extends AppModel {

/**
 * @see Model::$actsAs
 */
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Containable',
    );

/**
 * @see Model::$belongsTo
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        ),
        'Question' => array(
            'className' => 'Question',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
        ),
    );
```

then in your Controller :

```
public function loadQuestions($productId) {
    $this->view = 'load_questions';
    $questions = $this->QuestionProduct->find('all', array (
        'fields' => array (
            'Question.id',
            'Question.question',
            'Question.is_optional',
            'Question.reason_optional',
            'Question.text_size'
        ),
        'conditions' => array (
            'QuestionProduct.product_id' => $productId
        ),
        'contain' => array('Product','Question')
    ));
    $this->set($questions);
}
```

It should make exactly the query you want, and I don't think it has any other way to produce that query.